# Elegant solution for $\int {\frac{\cos(y)}{\sin^2(y)+\sin(y)-6}}dy$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have the following integral: $\int {\frac{\cos(y)}{\sin^2(y)+\sin(y)-6}}dy$

I already know the solution, but it needs three substitutions. Is there a simpler, more elegant way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int { \frac { \cos { \left( x \right)  } dx }{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ \left( x \right)  } +\sin { \left( x \right)  } -6 }  } =\int { \frac { d\sin { \left( x \right)  }  }{ \left( \sin { \left( x \right) +3 }  \right) \left( \sin { \left( x \right) -2 }  
\right)  }  } $$
Let $t=\sin { \left( x \right)  } $ then
$$\frac { 1 }{ \left( t+3 \right) \left( t-2 \right)  } =\frac { A }{ t+3 } +\frac { B }{ t-2 } $$
$$1=A\left( t-2 \right) +B\left( t+3 \right) \\ 1=\left( A+B \right) t-2A+3B\\ \begin{cases} A+B=0 \\ -2A+3B=1 \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} A=-B \\ 2B+3B=1 \end{cases}\Rightarrow B=\frac { 1 }{ 5 } ,A=-\frac { 1 }{ 5 } $$ so 
$\frac { 1 }{ \left( t+3 \right) \left( t-2 \right)  } =\frac { 1 }{ 5 } \left( \frac { 1 }{ t-2 } -\frac { 1 }{ t+3 }  \right) $
$$\\ \\ \\ \frac { 1 }{ 5 } \int { \left( \frac { 1 }{ t-2 } -\frac { 1 }{ t+3 }  \right) dt=\frac { 1 }{ 5 } \int { \frac { dt }{ t-2 }  } -\frac { 1 }{ 5 } \int { \frac { dt }{ t+3 } = }  } $$ $$=\frac { 1 }{ 5 } \int { \frac { d\left( t-2 \right)  }{ t-2 }  } -\frac { 1 }{ 5 } \int { \frac { d\left( t+3 \right)  }{ t+3 } =\frac { 1 }{ 5 } \left[ \ln { \left| t-2 \right|  } -\ln { \left| t+3 \right|  }  \right] =\frac { 1 }{ 5 } \ln { \left| \frac { t-2 }{ t+3 }  \right| +C }  }  $$
Hence $t=\sin { \left( x \right)  } $,$$\int { \frac { \cos { \left( x \right)  } dx }{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ \left( x \right)  } +\sin { \left( x \right)  } -6 }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 5 } \ln { \left| \frac { \sin { \left( x \right) -2 }  }{ \sin { \left( x \right) +3 }  }  \right|  } +C$$

Comment: The second expression seems to conflict with Blex's answer. Is it correct?

Comment: @Symeof,thanks for the  point i corrected it

Comment: How do you go from step 2 to step 3?

Comment: I will edit it now to be more clearly

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that it can be written more elegantly than:
$$
\int \frac{d(\sin \, y)}{(\sin \, y + 3)(\sin \, y - 2)}
$$

Comment: From there, is it possible to solve it with less than three substitutions?

Comment: from here decompose the fraction product in sum of fractions (as better explained in some other answers), then directly integrate remembering that $d(f(x) + c) = d(f(x))$. Here substitutions are useful to simplify visually but aren't strictly required.

Comment: Like Batanni's answer? Do you agree with it?

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Make the substitution, $\sin x=u$

Now $u^2+u-6=(u+3)(u-2)$ and use $(u+3)-(u-2)=5$

Answer (score 2):

$u=\sin y$ reduces the integrand to
$$\int \frac{du}{(u-2)(u+3)} = \int \frac{du}{5(u-2)}-\int\frac{du}{5(u+3)}
   = \frac{1}{5} \ln \left|\frac{\sin x-2}{\sin x+3} \right|+c
$$

Comment: Using MathJax makes your answers much more readable. Please learn it and thank you for contributing to the site.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int {\frac{\cos(y)}{\sin^2(y)+\sin(y)-6}}dy=$$

---

(Substitute $u=\sin(y)$ and $du=\cos(y)dy$):

---

$$\int\frac{1}{u^2+u-6}du=$$
$$\int\frac{1}{\left(u+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{25}{4}}du=$$

---

(Substitute $s=u+\frac{1}{2}$ and $ds=du$):

---

$$\int\frac{1}{s^2-\frac{25}{4}}ds=$$
$$\int-\frac{4}{25(1-\frac{4s^2}{25})}ds=$$
$$-\frac{4}{25}\int\frac{1}{1-\frac{4s^2}{25}}ds=$$

---

(Substitute $p=\frac{2s}{5}$ and $dp=\frac{2}{5}ds$):

---

$$-\frac{2}{5}\int\frac{1}{1-p^2}dp=$$
$$-\frac{2}{5}\tanh^{-1}\left(p\right)+C=$$
$$-\frac{2}{5}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{2s}{5}\right)+C=$$
$$-\frac{2}{5}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{2\left(u+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{5}\right)+C=$$
$$-\frac{2}{5}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{2\left(\sin(y)+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{5}\right)+C=$$
$$-\frac{2}{5}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sin(y)+1}{5}\right)+C$$

Comment: Very nice presentation (+1).
Incidentally it's exactly the same steps as wolfram alpha... This is actually the way I wanted to avoid. As I said in my question, I look for a way to do it without three substitutions. Is it possible?

Comment: Mathematica gave me a much more complicated step-by-step solution, so this is the fastest way I can solve your problem